# How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?

Tags: unity-2d, desktop-environments, qt

I [read](https://bfiller.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/unity-2d/) that there is now a 2D version of Unity built on [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). How do I install it, and once it's installed, how do I switch to it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### For 11.10, 12.04, & 12.10

Users of 11.10 and above have Unity 2D installed by default already.

To use it, logout, you will be confronted by the LightDM manager.

Then, click the little cog wheel, and select `Ubuntu 2D`.

Then, enter your password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you'll be logged into Unity 2D.

[image]

For 13.04, no need to do this - they have integrated the Unity 2D and Unity 3D environments.

Comment: is the cog wheel position saved for succeeding logins?

Comment: in which file is this setting saved?

Comment: it is indeed saved for succeeding logins. as for were, no clue.

Comment: 13.04, no such thing is present on the login page.

Comment: @KarelBílek fixed.

Comment: According to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143639): `Unity 2D was removed from 12.10 onwards.`

Answer (score 25):

### For 10.10

For people running 10.10 you can add the [Unity 2D PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eunity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily).

Go to Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit (Menu) -> Software Sources -> Other Software (tab) -> Add  and then paste `ppa:unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily` and then install `unity-2d` from the software center.

This will install all of the necessary dependencies to run Unity 2D, including a "Unity 2D" session that you'll need to login with. Then log out and when logging back in select "Unity 2D" at the bottom of the login screen.

[image]
<sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/961020.png))</sub>

#### Command Line Instructions

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Just installed this 0n 10.10 Netbook Edition and the difference in performance is huge - much better usability

Answer (score 21):

### For 11.04

Users of 11.04 can install [unity-2d[image: Install unity-2d]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unity-2d)
from the archive.

This will install all of the necessary dependencies to run Unity 2D, including a "Unity 2D" session that you'll need to login with. Then log out and when logging back in select "Unity 2D" at the bottom of the login screen.

[image]
<sub>(source: [xrmb2.net](https://img.xrmb2.net/images/961020.png))</sub>

#### Command Line Instructions

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

Comment: I think the relevant package is now unity-2d not -default-settings.

Comment: Natty users can of course also use the daily ppa if they prefer.

Answer (score 5):

### For 13.04 and onwards

---

***According to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143639):***

> Unity 2D was removed from 12.10 onwards. We now have something called llvmpipe which has the purpose of providing Unity 3D on lower specified PCs.

I don't think there will be interest in [resurrecting 2D development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_(display_server)).

I know this is not a direct answer to the question posted, but it rather leaves you with two possible choices *(if you seriously need **Unity 2D**)*:

1. Reinstall and stick with 12.04 (currently 12.04.2).
2. Use the ["fallback" session](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?s=5f31a284d7334dadb8303aba8e857a03&attachmentid=243244&d=1369844343) in either 12.10 or 13.04.

Comment: Link to "fallback session" appears to be a private message or some other thing that public users lack permissions to - please copy/paste into this answer. This appears to cover the intended material http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/no-unity-here-enable-classic-gnome-in-ubuntu-13-04/