# Is there any fix for ATI HD 4350 With Unity?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ati

I Love the unity interface... so I installed the interface in my desktop pc and I installed the Ati Official Drivers, I recently Bought an Ati HD 4350, and the interface starts but very Sluggish and when I open an app, it just frezees constanly, even the title bars from the windows look distorsionated.

Thanks for the answers.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: have you installed the proper drivers?, also unity on 10.10 uses mutter for compositing and unity for 11.04 uses compiz, and mutter just isn't as good as compiz

Comment: Yes, it has the Ati Catalyst Drivers... in Linux MInt 10 Same thing happened :s

Comment: I would strongly suggest using Unity with 11.04 (compiz version). The 10.10 (Mutter version) never worked properly on mine

Comment: I would strongly advise against using the 11.04 version of Unity until April when it is released. At the moment it is not stable.

Answer (score 2):

I have an ATI Radeon HD 4350 in my Desktop.

My advice is not to use the Official ATI drivers. The "default" open source drivers work perfectly for me, both with Ubuntu's normal interface and in Unity. Unity is not sluggish, does not freeze, or have corruption of the window borders for me.

To deactivate the Official ATI drivers you need to go to System->Administration->Additional Drivers (but if you installed them using some other method, you may have to do uninstall them differently).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So, i can't make it work, with the propietary ones? the thing that worries me, is the flash and 1080p performance

Comment: I haven't found flash performance or video playback to be problematic (although I don't have any 1080p videos). If I was you I'd give it a go, you can always change back to the proprietary drivers if you want to.

Comment: My experience has been that the proprietary ATI driver is terrible, especially for video playback while the open source driver works great.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 2D unity instead of "default" unity.

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Comment: Well, i deactivate the Propietary drivers... now, when i got into unity it crash and my computer reboots... so, i think unity for me until Natty