# Performance being really choppy with ATI drivers

Tags: unity, ati

I just updated to the latest version (11.04) yesterday, and ever since then, the system has been really choppy.

I used to have 10.10 installed, and that was running smooth.

Anyone also experiencing this? Any fixes?

I'm only running Chrome and Netbeans...

Comment: I have already posted a bug regarding the same and it has been marked as duplicate of bug no:**763005** And the original bug has been approved by Canonical, so expect a solution from Ubuntu. You can follow the development of this at: [Launch pad bug link: 763005](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/763005)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Install **CompizConfig SettingsManager**

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

   - Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)
2. Click on the **Composite** tab, and
   un-check **Detect refresh rate**.

   [image]

   [image]
3. Click on the **OpenGL** tab, and un-check **Sync to Vblank**.

   [image][image]

Comment: Done - is this something that should take effect immediately, or is a restart required?

Comment: Oh wow... never mind - it seems to have fixed the issue, for the most part. It's not perfect still, but a lot better.

Comment: I have an ATI card too, and Unity was SOOOO choppy at first. but disabling that helped a lot. There are a few more options in Compiz related to tweaking the refresh rate that you may want to look into. Glad it all worked out for you.

Comment: xil3, I updated my answer with another step that may also help you.

Comment: This didn't help a bit. Even typing in Firefox makes the CPU jump to 50% (well, 100% for one core).

Comment: Hmm, that sounda like you may be having a separate problem. Perhaps try creating a new question, stating that you've read, and tried all of the similar questions. But the fact that your CPU jumping *that* high makes me think it is something else.

Comment: Also happening to me.. I have implemented the solution you have listed but it only helps a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, but, however, in my case adjusting compiz settings *didn't help a lot*.

I also had ATI drivers installed. Then I noticed ATI had JUST released **new** ones, which are said to have ***much better supprot for*** the latest X and ***Unity***. However, ATI released them too late, and they *failed to get into Ubuntu repositories*.

What I reccoment you is to **uninstall the ATI driver** (fglrx) Ubuntu installed for you, and **get the newest one from the ATI's site**: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

In my case this provided incredible improvement of overall performance. I hope it will help you too!

Comment: __Overemphasise__ _text_ ___much___?

Answer (score -1):

This link aways help me with my Radeon

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, [it would be preferrable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.