# moving windows lags after update to Natty

Tags: 11.04, compiz, graphics, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance being really choppy with ATI drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers)

I just upgraded my main machine to Natty. I have an ATI 2600 with the proprietary ATI driver. It worked fine with Maverick on both 3D games and the Compiz desktop.

Now games still work, but merely moving windows laggs really annoyingly. Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Compiz Config Settings Manager and launch it. You need to follow these steps:

1. Go to Composite plugin and disable 'Detect Refresh Rate'
2. In the option below, enter your monitor refresh rate. Mine is 60.
3. Now go to OpenGL Plugin and disable 'Sync to Vblank'
4. Logout and come back.

Comment: Awesome! I did not even need to log out. You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

1. Install compiz-manager by `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Go to "CompizConfig Settings Manager"
3. In OpenGL pluging deselect "Sync to VBlank"

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but, however, in my case adjusting compiz settings *didn't help a lot*.

I also had ATI drivers installed. Then I noticed ATI had JUST released **new** ones, which are said to have ***much better supprot for*** the latest X and ***Unity***. However, ATI released them too late, and they *failed to get into Ubuntu repositories*.

What I reccoment you is to **uninstall the ATI driver** (fglrx) Ubuntu installed for you, and **get the newest one from the ATI's site**: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

In my case this provided incredible improvement of overall performance. I hope it will help you too!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but it works a bit better with  OpenGL plugin **select** "Sync to VBlank". It is usable but lags and before upgrading it does not. So it seems to be a bug. That not every thing works well is also shown by the fact that compiz becomes unusable if I set the cube transparent. Than it lags like hell. I hope some expert will find a solution soon. Maybe it has something to do with the ATI-Driver?

Must be a Compiz bug: ***There is a bug report for this problem, please vote!*** [Compiz effects slow and laggy on Natty with ATI card](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/768275)

Comment: Before upgrade, you used No effects or Medium effects? I think with Maximum effect it lags on 10.10 too... And in Unity default is Maximum. So you can use Classic Ubuntu or maybe Unity2D

Comment: I used maximum effects before upgrading with out any problems. Even my Netbook with atom an intel graphik device does maximum effects with out lags in 10.10. Wobbeling windows as well as desktop cube with transparency.But after upgrading the same problem occurs with Unity and »Ubuntu Classic«. It seems to be an serious Compiz bug.

Comment: For Intel graphics, I would recommend x-swat repository (with newest version of xorg and drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this answer, but to be honest, I already did this. I am using catalyst version 11.3 (Release Date 4/27/2011) witch is, as fare as I know the latest release. To use this driver instead of those witch are shipped with Ubuntu was my first guess, but it did't work out. Thank you anyway!