# 3D compiz effects choppy and slow. How to fix?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, ati, 3d

I have a ATI proprietary drivers but it makes the Unity 3D very slow except 2D. Like everything works but it runs a bit slow and choppy. You could even see it when you see the loading circles on the Chromium browser. Also it shows choppiness when I have the wobbly windows turned on. Can someone help me fix?

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, but, however, in my case adjusting compiz settings *didn't help a lot*.

I also had ATI drivers installed. Then I noticed ATI had JUST released **new** ones, which are said to have ***much better supprot for*** the latest X and ***Unity***. However, ATI released them too late, and they *failed to get into Ubuntu repositories*.

What I reccoment you is to **uninstall the ATI driver** (fglrx) Ubuntu installed for you, and **get the newest one from the ATI's site**: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

In my case this provided incredible improvement of overall performance. I hope it will help you too!

Comment: i dont know to install it can u help me???

Comment: When you have downloaded the driver (it should be a .run file) double-click it, choose "run in terminal" (or something similar, as I use a translated version of ubuntu), and follow the displayed instructions. And be sure to uninstall the driver you use before you begin installation!

Comment: ok.....and how to uninstall...im sorry...im 15 and im kinda new here lol

Comment: You can remove them both by using "hardware drivers" from the System Settings, or by typing `sudo apt-get purge fglrx` from terminal.

Comment: @Yanick: I'm glad to hear! :) mine is HD 3650, by the way :)

Comment: @Kevin You should ask how to install the drivers as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

It's https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/763005

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.