# Graphical features are quite slow on an HD Radeon 3200

Tags: laptop, ati

I just got new laptop and it had Windows 7 -preinstalled. Laptop was quite fast with Windows 7. Anyway, I basically only watch videos, IRC and code PHP with this laptop, so I thought that Ubuntu would be better choice for me, so I installed it.

Computer is running tasks quite fast, but graphical features just are too slow to be true. For example, when I move window to another place, I don't see any transition, only the start place and then it jumps to the place I dragged it.

Some info about the computer:

- Packard Bell Easynote TJ61, 4GB DDR2 RAM, AMD Athlon 64 X2 QL-64

~$ fglrxinfo*

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 3200 Graphics
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11161 Compatibility Profile Context
```

- I tried this and it sped up a bit: [3D compiz effects choppy and slow. How to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38535/3d-compiz-effects-choppy-and-slow-how-to-fix)

Comment: Can you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/38535/3d-compiz-effects-choppy-and-slow-how-to-fix

Comment: It's a tiny bit faster, didn't help much :/ Oh, and I use GNOME Classic instead of Unity.

Comment: It sounds as if you have done all you can. At this point, this question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out:

"Installed ATI drivers from http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx (cat /etc/ati/amdpcsdb | grep "Catalyst_Version" should give you S11.11)
Configured Compiz Performance being really choppy with ATI drivers (Alan's answer)
Used GNOME Classic (no effects) instead of GNOME Classic"