# Windows in Unity are Jumpy

Tags: unity, nvidia, window-manager

Just running the new Ubuntu, I've noticed that my Windows don't move smoothly around the screen. Instead, they're jumpy and jerky.

I have a GeForce 560ti.  This is a higher end video card.  I'm perplexed as to why something so simple as Windows compositing is so difficult.

Yes, I am using the nvidia binary drivers.

Comment: See a demonstration here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTHCbvPcWsY

Comment: I have heard similar reports of performance issues. It has been reported that this issue happens on NVidia system after using Unity for a little while. Could be a driver issue. I will post updates on the bug report you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created the following bug over at launchpad regarding this issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/774414

This appears to be an issue with compiz.  Anyone experiencing this same issue is encouraged to head over there and add their voice to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like it could be `vblank`-related.

See [the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers) for disabling it.

Let me know if that works and I'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. Windows still jump around.

Comment: @Omega Tried firing in `compiz --replace` after changing the setting?

Comment: Just did that now to be certain, and no.  No luck.  Windows are still VERY jumpy when I try to move them around.

Comment: I just tried running glxgears and the performance is absolutely dreadful.  Almost completely hangs my desktop.  Seems like 3D is seriously broken with compiz and/or Unity on 11.04?!

Comment: I should add, this system runs 3D games just fine under Windows 7.

Comment: glxgears is a hog here too (nvidia also) but it claims to be running fast. I find that games work just fine though. Try opening up `nvidia-settings`, going to the OpenGL settings page and enabling `Sync to VBlank`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work either.  Windows still jumpy when they move around. This really seems Unity+Compiz related.

Comment: That's very odd - I have a rather old nvidia (well 2 years isn't rather old - but you get my point), and it's fine here. You may have an option your xorg.conf that doesn't need to be there, or a bad compiz option that nVidia's driver doesn't like (like I think the loose binding option causes trouble, but I don't remember). Trust me the problem is probably a configuration, not unity/compiz.

Comment: Roland: My xorg has exactly ONE entry which is to disable the nvidia splash screen.  Otherwise, it's empty.