# Do I really need ATI proprietary drivers?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, ati, hdmi, proprietary

Ever since I installed 11.04, I have problems with ATI. If I don't enable it, am I still able to use HDMI with no problems?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't say about HDMI, but my guess would be no.

However, there is a known problem with the ATI Proprietary driver. Actually, not sure what the problem is, but I know of a fix:

- [Performance being really choppy with ATI drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

I am using 11.10 without the proprietary drivers. HDMI works quite well with it. The only things not working are the sound through HDMI-out though and some OpenGL games. If you don't care about this, there's a great chance that you can use the open drivers.
If they don't run out of the box, you could try adding `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` or even `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` (I wouldn't recommend the later for a stable working environment though).