# Poor Performance with Intel HD 3000 GPU

Tags: performance, intel-graphics

I am running the 8,1 Macbook Pro. It has the integrated Intel HD 300 gpu. I've noticed the graphics performance is drastically worse in Ubuntu than in OS X. I tested this using the bullet physics library (http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) demos. In OS X, they all run flawlessly and smooth. In Ubuntu on the same laptop they're unusable. I can't properly interact with them because they hang so much and the framerate is so low.

Is this a driver issue? Any fixes or possibility of this being fixed?

I was planning on working with some bullet stuff, but the performance is much worse than is reasonable.

Comment: Please see my answer here, it may still apply to your GPU.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers/38042#38042

Comment: That didn't seem to have any perceptible effect on performance. I should also note that unity and compiz in general runs perfectly smooth.

Comment: This is very odd. I'm afraid my knowledge is limited, so I can't aid you beyond that. But no doubt someone else here can, if you don't receive an answer after a few days I will post a bounty for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also running Intel HD 3000 on Thinkpad T420. Using standard 11.04 driver, even glxgears is very choppy and pressing the windows button to access search is unresponsive. I've came across a better HD3000 driver here:

http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers

Now the performance improved a bit, glxgears managed to get 60fps constantly although there still some hiccups and still some graphical glitch in games like nexuiz and tremulous. Nexuiz is still not playable though.

Comment: My benchmark (2.5 years latter): using dell vostro 3550, same intel hd 3000, ubuntu 11.11, running glxgears: 850fps