# Colors on display are washed out

Tags: display

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series, with an Intel HD5500 graphics card, running Ubuntu 14.04. My problem is that the colors on the screen are all washed out. They also look too blue. I have tried adjusting gamma and contrast using xcalib, but all it does is make the problem worse. I have also tried using Gnome Color Manager, but the calibration button is grayed out. I've looked on the Intel website for different drivers, but they only list basic development drivers with no support.

I can use xgamma to increase or decrease the gamma, and this does help, but what I really need is to increase the contrast. Contrast, via xcalib, is already 100%. It seems, with xcalib, all I can do is lower values, when what I need to do is increase them. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Try running the following command from a terminal while logged in:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

Your screen will probably flicker/turn off momentarily to apply the new settings.

If that fixes your problem, you can add this command to your `~/.xprofile` file so that it runs whenever you log in to the graphical environment:

```
echo 'xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"' >> ~/.xprofile
```

Hope that helps! It took me months to discover this fix!

Comment: Just to help here, mine was HDMI-1 rather that HDMI1. If you just do 'xrandr' it will tell you which monitors and modes each monitor is on. Interestingly my 2nd monitor was DP-1 as I'm using a USB-C hub, but this worked a charm!

Comment: Woks on my Lenovo laptop when replacing HDMI with eDP-1 and in general the --output value is the value of: xrandr | grep " connected" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"

Comment: I get the following error message: `X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  56`

Comment: Works with VGA too (my HDMI output doesn't work properly so I have to use VGA)

Comment: @Alexej Magura
You probably aren't using HDMI1, do what the top comment says

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue. Just curious, what does this actually do? I'm surprised this wasn't the default (I just used it on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: @HeathMitchell For me, if I specify the wrong output the command returns `warning: output HDMI0 not found; ignoring \ X Error of failed request:  BadRROutput (invalid Output parameter)`. I think `BadName ...` like @AlexejMagura states refers to something passed to the `--set` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can't, unless your OEM gives you the colour software for Linux or calibrated `.icm`/`.icc` profiles. I've Samsung NP370R4V-XXXX, I've a motherboard software called "display colour profiles", and "Settings" software. In settings software, there are calibrated profiles I can choose. Unless the screen is blueish, bad colour like on Linux.

So, you need calibrated profiles or colour software by your Manufacturer. Or buy a colour calibration machine. It would be better if anyone can build a software that copies current calibrated/applied colour RGB, display colour info from windows, convert, and set into Linux. Intel HD Graphics Control Panel is a better place for RGB, related colours info. The display colour is the only thing that forces me to stay in Windows, I would love to use Linux. A lot of people can't use Linux only for this.