# How can I fix the compiz effects lag in unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, nvidia

I've recently installed ubuntu 11.04, and I actually liked Unity (although many others prefer Gnome), but there seems to be a lag problem. Every time I press the super button to bring out the Dash, or Super+W to show all windows, or any other action that involves some sort of effect, the effect lags a bit, and it could get really annoying.

I've seen a fix using CompizConfig Settings Manager, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

I've got a NVidia 9800 GT 1 GB video card, a 2 GB Ram, and not sure about the CPU (if you need it, tell me and I'll figure it out).

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Install the CCSM `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

and look at this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/38042/46312)