# Compiz animations jittery with an ATI Radeon HD 6520G 

Tags: 11.10, compiz, xorg, ati, fglrx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance being really choppy with ATI drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers)

I have Ubuntu 11.10 64bit installed on a machine with an AMD A6-3400M CPU, and a Radeon HD 6520G card. For some reason all compiz animations are very jittery and unpleasant to look at.

I have the ATI FGLRX driver installed but when I try to install the version with post-release updates from jockey it says installation failed.

I have tried downloading compiz config, and setting the refresh rate to 60hz (from 50hz, I read online that this helps) but it always changes back to 50, even after I check off not to detect the refresh rate.

If need be, I can post the jockey log.

Perhaps the issue is with 64 bit ubuntu, but if I install 32 bit, will it be able to address all 6GB of my ram? I know windows 32 bit can't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers

Comment: Fixed it. I don't know how I didn't find it. Hope you excuse my negligence, and thank you very much.

Comment: 32-bit Memory limitation: Are you thinking about Win 7, not ubuntu?

Comment: @Roman RE: Memory limit - All supported versions of Ubuntu have the PAE (Physical Address Extension) kernels. So you will be able to address all 6GB of ram even with 32bit