# ATI Catalyst drivers slowness

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati

I have managed to install the drivers, but after installing those drivers moving different windows such as browser is very laggy.

Why is that? I also tried older drivers, but they all have the same problem. I have ATI Radeon HD5850.

I installed this driver: AMD Catalyst™ 11.11 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver. I can't remember how I installed it, because I installed Ubuntu again because of the drivers. All I remember that it was very easy. The file was .run. I have only one screen (Asus VE247**)

Comment: What drivers did you install and how? What version? Please add that information to the question.

Comment: Do you have multiple screens?

Comment: I get a lot of artifacting using xinerama for many screens, but slow drags is not an issue for me.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/38042/43594 and see if those two items work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install **CompizConfig Settings Manager**

1. Run it.
2. Click on OpenGL.
3. Set texture filter to FAST.
4. Uncheck sync to vblank.
5. log out and back on.

**Note:** You may need to enable tear free in Catalyst afterwards.

Enjoy.