# windows are moving slowly on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: compiz, effects

> Video Card : ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650

Although my video card ATI when i check system info

> Driver : VESA: M86  Experience :  Fallback

i checked compiz config manager and disable all effects insipite of this windows are moving slowly.It does not for all windows,for example when i use google chrome and scrool up/down there is no effect but when i move window to another position it moves slowly but when i use pdf reader when i scrool up or down it moves slowly.How can i solve this ? i use core 2 duo intel cpu and run ubuntu 11.10.

> Edit : 
>   The Solution : Upgrade kernel and then update all graphic card
>   drivers.Now there is no problem .

Comment: Can you add what video card you have?

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers

Comment: @JorgeCastro this link could not help me

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NVIDA or ATI graphics card I'd recommend installing the proprietary drivers.

System Settings --> Additional Drivers

I had that issue on my old Pentium 4 with 2GB of RAM.

Good Luck

Comment: i install from http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx but there is no different

Comment: especially i could not install because at the end of the installation it showed an error message : "There were errors during installation.Details can be found /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.lpg"