# Window chrome disappears and reappears causing jumpy windows

Tags: unity, 13.10, ati, virtualbox, compiz

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 in VirtualBox. The host machine is running Windows 7 with an ATI Radeon HD 5570 video card, 12 GB of memory, 2 quad core i7 CPUs. I've given the virtual machine 4GB of memory, 128 MB of video memory, 1 CPU, and checked the 3d acceleration box in VirtualBox (without 3d checked everything runs like molasses in the winter time).

Every 5 or 10 minutes some of my windows start flipping between a chrome state (the title bar is visible) to a no chrome state (the title bar disappears) which makes the windows jump up and down.  This happens with Chrome, Firefox, and Sublime which are pretty much the only apps I use on this box.  For Chrome and Firefox, if I delete the user preferences folder then it temporarily seems to fix things. But now it started with Sublime and I haven't found a good fix yet which means I can't currently do any work.

Here is a .gif of the problem:

[image]

Why is this happening and what do I need to do to permanently fix it?

Comment: Did you try with any other virtualization software? For eg. [VMware Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0)?

Comment: No I haven't. It sounds like I would need to convert my .vdi to a .vmdk first and I was hoping I wouldn't need to go down that route. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 in another VM on the same machine and have never seen this problem so I was hoping there was a quick fix.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers)?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here: I had the same problem on WinXP, and forcing screen DPI helped. Here are the [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi) for Ubuntu, try setting it to 120. Won't hurt anyway. 
P.S. When you solve the problem, please take time to file a bug at Launchpad on it.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps:

1>open chrome.Go to chrome://flags/ in address bar.

2>Click on reset all to default.chrome will restart.

3>Now go to chrome://gpu/

4> Check if anything is in red, there lies your problem.