# Can I try the 2d version of Unity on a Live CD?

Tags: unity, 11.04

My graphics card doesn't support 3d. can I try out the 2d version on the live cd?

Answer (score 1):

No, in ubuntu 11.04 it isn't installed by default. You can try to install it on the live cd.

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)