# How to remove GNOME classic session and associated packages?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, session, gnome-classic

Ok have been testing unity and I love it. And I have heard that unity-2d will be fallback session from 11.10. I would like to make 11.04 the same without breaking the functionality of unity.

So I would Like to know how can I get just ubuntu(.i.e. Unity) and unity-2d as session choice in 11.04 and completely remove gnome classic desktop session choice(If Possible) ?? What packages shall I purge for this without hindering my desktop experience ??

By the way I have [already installed unity-2d](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop) and its quite nice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NB: You SHOULD NOT do this on a production system unless you are willing to face potential breakage.**

I would suggest simply removing the Ubuntu classic session's session file (I believe this is somewhere within `/etc/X11`).

You could then remove the `gnome-panel` package, but I wouldn't suggest removing anything else for now. *Better safe than sorry.*

Comment: Well I did remove `gnome-applets`, `gnome-panel` and seems its the only thing I can do at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Those packages don't add much overhead to your system, perhaps 50MB total. Relax, enjoy Unity, the rest will drop away in 11.10!

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get remove gnome-session-fallback` in terminal should help you remove the Gnome classic environment in 11.10 in 11.04 you already have a classic session

Comment: `gnome-session-fallback` doesn't provide the GNOME 2 "Classic" desktop present in Ubuntu 11.04. [That package doesn't even exist in 11.04.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-session-fallback&searchon=names&suite=natty&section=all)