# Geforce Go 7300/7400 Blacklisted, Can I Still Run Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, nvidia

Unity won't run on my new Ubuntu 11.04 install (with a Nvidia GeForce GO 7400). Ubuntu classic desktop works though, I tried all different drivers provided in the repositories.

Doing <kbd>System</kbd> → <kbd>Administration</kbd> → <kbd>Additional Drivers</kbd> gives me a warning :

> This driver is activated but not currently in use.

I even tried the Nvidia driver from the official Homepage.

After some googling, I found the tool `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` which tells me that my card is blacklisted. The other tests show a green yes.

Is this a bug? Or is my card too old which would be pretty surprising for me :P ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

We blacklisted Geforce Go 7300/7400 because of some freezes at startup with the "nvidia-current" driver.

It seems that unity 3D can run with the "nvidia 173" driver with those card. However, you will get some slowness, you are warned!

So, to workaround the detection at startup, you can:

1. `sudo nano /etc/environment`
2. add: `UNITY_FORCE_START=1`
3. Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
4. reboot

Ensure you are choosing the "ubuntu" session in gdm (default). This will bypass the detection and try to start unity 3D.

Comment: that work around worked for me. i adjusted the file manually not with nano and it worked! i have unity now. thanks, hope the new drivers will work soon with the go 7300

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, here's the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/726496) about this issue.

Another option you've got is to use the experimental 3D support with the open source **nouveau** driver. It's probably slower than the proprietary nvidia driver, but it's been working great for me.

In order to install it, just open the application dash with the `Super`+`A` key combination, start typing '`jockey`' without the quotes and select the *Additional Drivers* result. This will start the jockey-gtk application, where you can select to install the nouveau driver with experimental 3D support.

You'll still need to force unity to run by adding `UNITY_FORCE_START=1` to `/etc/environment`, as explained in the other answer

Comment: FWIW, you may need to edit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and remove nouveau from the blacklist to see it in the "Additional Drivers" screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually try unity-2D:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Comment: Yes. That would be an option. Thanks. But is there no possibility to use the normal one? I don't understand how a desktop needs so many grafical features. I can play 3D games with my card XD

Answer (score 0):

I have a NVIDIA GeForece FX 5700LE and trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 I found this question when I discovered that unity did not support my video card.

While my answer does not answer the question, it might help other in the same situation who come across this question.

In my case didrocks' solution did not work.  I had to punt unity and go with gnome.

1. @terminal: `sudo apt-get gnome-session-flashback`
2. Reboot
3. @login screen: click the icon to the upper right of name and select: `GNOME Flashback (Metacity).`