# Is The Nvidia Geforce 7300 LE Blacklisted?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia, blacklist

I have a Geforce 7300 LE. Is that blacklisted in Natty? Are there any video card checking utilities available that will check compatibility with Natty before downloading/installing? I want to make sure it works before I download.

Answer (score 1):

I am running a GeForce 7300 too. Just select nvidia-173 drivers, not nvidia-current, and add `UNITY_FORCE_START=1` in `/etc/environment`.
It works.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I get brave enough to upgrade to Natty I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Jorge. Selecting the nvidia 173 driver worked for me - I didn't change /etc/environment, just restarted with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Q&A is helpful for you:
[Geforce Go 7300/7400 Blacklisted, Can I Still Run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity/38728#38728)
Or you can use this tool to check compatibility:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

Comment: Isn't that test utility a part of Natty? I am looking for something that can be run without downloading/installing it.

Comment: Hm, obviousliy there are just packages for 11.04 and 11.10 ([link]https://launchpad.net/nux/+packages). Sorry, I don't know any other tool, but maybe someone else knows about a testing tool...