# How to use a proprietary driver

Tags: unity, drivers, unity-2d, proprietary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nvidia driver activated but currently not in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37084/nvidia-driver-activated-but-currently-not-in-use)

I've just installed Ubuntu on a new machine and it work perfectly except for the NVidia Graphics driver. When booting from the USB everything worked fine but Ubuntu sent me to the "classic" interface when I booted for the first time.

I installed Unity 2D but it's really not the same thing. Now even when I log on with the Ubuntu interface selected (Unity 3D) Ubuntu logs on with the 2D interface.

I checked the "additional drivers" tool and it tells me that the driver is "activated but not in use"

What can I do to resolve the problem?

Update: here's a screenshot of the "additional drivers" utility
[image: Addtitional Drivers activated but not in use]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known issue: Have a look at this Questions, I'm sure this will help you to solve your problem:
[Is The Nvidia Geforce 7300 LE Blacklisted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38853/is-the-nvidia-geforce-7300-le-blacklisted/38854#38854)

and 
[Geforce Go 7300/7400 blacklisted, can I still run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity/38728)