# Is it possible to use binary nvidia driver with GeForce 7300 SE?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I have an Nvidia GeForce 7300 SE.  It worked fine with the nvidia driver when I was using 10.10.  When I upgraded to 12.04, the (nvidia-current) binary driver failed---I couldn't even get a login screen.  The "nouveau" driver works okay, but the display is quite sluggish.

I've read about the fact that my GeForce is blacklisted ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity/38728#38728) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38853/is-the-nvidia-geforce-7300-le-blacklisted)).  But, when I tried the suggested workaround of using [nvidia-173](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-173), I discovered that it wouldn't install because of a failed dependency: xorg-video-abi-10 (Package not available).  The "precise" [nvidia-173 package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-173) notes this (dependency bug?)

So, my real question: is there a GeForce 7300 SE workaround for 12.04?

Comment: jrennie, this is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/980298) (regression) with the 295.40 driver that ships with 12.04.  nVidia has released 295.49 that fixes this, but as far as I can tell, this hasn't been pushed to the ubuntu repos yet.  It may appear in the [ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) ppa soon or hopefully the nvidia-current-updates package.  Until then you could [download](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) and install the driver manually, or suffer with nouveau.

Comment: Looks like my problem may be different---295.49 still gives me a segfault; I added a comment to the bug.

Comment: That is too bad. nVidia lists your card as supported by the 295.49 driver. It worked for me, though I am not using the same card.  I suppose you could try the 302.07 beta driver.  Otherwise, I got nada.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, Im using Linux Mint, but i guess that all repositories in this os is still the same as in Ubuntu, Using Linux Mint Maya (Ubuntu 12.04 equivalent in precise) I followed this forum

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=102602

Since Nvidia-96 is not available on any higher versions (precise and upper i guess), in this forum, they tried to get the Nvidia package to a lower ubuntu version (oneiric) and use it to their current OS and downgrade their xorg to oneiric.

Now these steps are still working in my system, and I'm using oneiric nvidia-96.
Nvidia-173 is also available to oneiric repository. But please read all the recommendations in the link above to avoid problems.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, and its very helpful that you included information on your own experience, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Does your computer use the GeForce 7300SE card, or another Nvidia card?