# Unity freezing ( new install )

Tags: unity

I just installed ubuntu 11.04 and after logging in for the first time , I enabled the restricted driver for my Nvidia 7300 LE card and enabled the same.
after rebooting , the system freezes (Unresponsive ).
So I rebooted the system and used the safe mode.. 
is my graphics card (Nvidia 7300 ) enough for unity ? , if its enough , please guide me how to get it working ..

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nvidia 7300's are blacklisted from Unity due to problems with those cards, sorry:

- [Geforce Go 7300/7400 Blacklisted, Can I Still Run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity)

Here's how to run Unity 2D:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Comment: So is my graphics card. Using the nvidia-173 drivers instead of nvidia-current fixed it for me though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing unity 2d:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)