# How do I always show the launcher (i.e. disable the auto-hide functionality)?

Tags: unity, compiz, 11.10, launcher

When I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10, the setting remained. Now that I have done a clean install of 11.10, the CCSM option does NOT work anymore and I can't seem to find a solution. Also note that I am NOT talking about Unity 2D.

- I've tried `unity --reset` and that does not help.
- Logging out and back in doesn't help
- Removing the hidden directories in my home directory doesn't help

Comment: Did you get all latest packages updates? I think it was a bug of Oneiric beta 2, on my PC it was solved with today updates.

Comment: You might try resetting your settings: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Comment: I tried to duplicate your problem, but deactivating the authide function works fine. Have you gotten the latest updates for the unity packages?

Comment: Confirmed - I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 11.10 today, and I have this problem.

Comment: ALso, resetting unity settings with `unity --reset` does not help.

Comment: sounds like  bug to me, maybe something specific to your hardware? You do have the unity option inside CCSM? I upgraded over the weekend, and had no issue like this (auto-hide now disabled)

Comment: For the case that this is hardware related: I'm experiencing these problems. I have the unity plugin configured and enabled in CCSM, and I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on an ASUS N53. (It doesn't seem to be only this setting - Unity doesn't seem to honor *any* settings specified in CCSM... =/)

Comment: I think what you can do is wipe out your compiz configuration from home directory hidden in `cache, config and gconf` and then use `ccsm` to change launcher from dodge windows to Never as many have suggested. Then if compiz doesnot restart do Alt+F2 and run `compiz --replace`

Comment: @sagarchalise: Tried that without success.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane and others: [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/878536) has been filed.

Comment: I've [uploaded](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/878536/+attachment/2574466/+files/lshw.txt) the output of `lshw` on my machine, in case this is hardware related.

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/878536) and as such is now closed.

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/q/155305/37991 (it works for Unity - don't go by the SCHEMA name Unity2d)

Answer (score 4):

In my case what I did was this:

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager:
   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
   or
   `sudo aptitude compizconfig-settings-manager`
   or GUI tools like **Software Center / Synaptic**
2. Open CCSM with dash menu (Press <kbd>SUPER</kbd> to open Dash):

[image]
3. Select **UNITY** plugin:

[image]
4. **DISABLE AUTO-HIDE**

Now you HAVE TO log out or reboot the computer for this to work. Same goes when changing the icon size in the launcher. It does not take effect the first time you change it. Only after rebooting will it work. At least for me.

[image]

NOTE - Stopping the Auto-Hide will save some trouble with some windows like the Back Button of Firefox been underneath the Launcher when it "auto-appears". It is **VERY IMPORTANT** you update the system (Check for updates with the Update Manager and apply all of them). Reboot and then do this answer. This way you save yourself some other troubles that have been fixed already with this minor updates.

As you can see in all the images the Launcher stays there in a fixed position. Saving me some seconds each time I need to search for something.

NOTE2 - Using `unity --reset` will only reset you to the default config it has after installing 11.10. Same goes for the default icons if you use `unity --reset-icons`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to generate all these screenshots. However, this is exactly what I'm trying, and it *isn't* working, because Unity apparently doesn't care what settings I enter in CCSM.

Comment: I see you have tried a lot of options but just in case, did you try other resolutions?. I mean after a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10. Did you per chance change the resolution to another smaller one to test how the launcher reacts.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that before, but I've now tried a multitude of both high and low resolutions with ratios from 4:3 to 16:10 (I have a 16:9 display) with no success in either of them.

Comment: Can you add to your question a link to a file that contains the ouput of `lshw` so we know the hardware you have and might help a little bit more with this.

Comment: Here you go: [lshw output](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/878536/+attachment/2574466/+files/lshw.txt)

Comment: Well I do not see anything that might cause that issue. Can I ask how did you execute the fresh install. I know is a dumb question but just to make know how you did it, what steps you took and if they hard drive was wiped clean before doing it.

Comment: I've reinstalled Ubuntu so many times over the past couple of days (due to other errors of mine), sometimes by wiping it all out and starting anew, sometimes by "upgrading" to the same version. This issue has always been there regardless. In other words, if I would wipe my hard drive clean and install Ubuntu 11.10 from a CD the regular 64-bit image from ubuntu.com, this issue would show up (most likely - I'm not going to actually do it, again...).

Comment: 16.04 doesn't have auto dodge :\

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Reinstall the CompizConfig Settings Manager

```
sudo apt-get autoremove compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then, search for it in the Dash, go to Unity Plugin (or something like that), and in the Experimental tab, you can change its configuration.

After that, restart your session, it should work fine, I just did it.

Comment: Nope. Launcher still dodges even though "hide launcher" is set to "never"...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bug report about this.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/887203

Sometimes the problem can be fixed with this:

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options`/launcher_hide_mode" 1
sleep 2
gconftool-2 --type int --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" 0
```

This does not work always.

Comment: Didn't work for me =(

Comment: By the way, you did see [my bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/878536) since earlier, right?

Comment: I did not see your bug report. A marked mine as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact same problem. After reading through one of the bug reports linked to above, and then following one of the links in there, I found this question: [Geforce Go 7300/7400 Blacklisted, Can I Still Run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity)

It turns out that the video card (in my case a nVidia 7300) was blacklisted, and even though I was logging into "Unity" and not "Unity 2D", it was still falling back to 2D mode because the card is blacklisted.

There is a workaround there about installing the nVidia 173 drivers and forcing Unity mode, and it works for me. I also tried it with the latest drivers, hoping the compatibility issues has been fixed, but the system locked up as soon as I logged in, so I had to go back to the nVidia 173 drivers.

The important parts from the link I posted:

Run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`. If you get a red "no" next to "Not blacklisted", then you've got this issue. Once you install the nVidia 173 driver, you can edit `/etc/environment` and add the following line:

```
UNITY_FORCE_START=1
```

Log out and back in, and you should be set. You now have to re-apply the settings in CompizConfig, but this time they should be respected.

Answer (score 0):

(total guess, but update your question with what happens).

Log out, and log in via a tty by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.

1. [Reset your Unity configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) by doing a `unity --reset`
2. Let's move compiz's settings out of the way in case they're messed up: `mv .compiz  .compiz-backup`
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>, then log in.
4. Now try to set the settings via CCSM
5. Log out and back in.

Comment: No success - nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

The "Hide Launcher" setting in CCSM [wasn't working for me](https://askubuntu.com/q/68820/27980) after updating to 11.10 but I found if I changed the setting to what I wanted and restarted X, it ended up working. Have you by change restarted X after changing the setting?

Comment: "restarted X"? I'm afraid I don't understand...

Comment: X is what renders your desktop. I just mean log out and log back in. Normally CCSM settings should apply right away but apparently there's a bug where you have to log out and in again.

Comment: That doesn't work for me - the settings still show up correctly in CCSM (i.e. hide launcher set to "never") even after a full system reset, but the launcher still doges windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can install gconf-editor and then change the setting by going to:

> apps > compiz > plugins > unityshell > screen0 > options

Edit the following option:

> launcher_hide_mode

Your options are:

> Make the launcher hide automatically after some time of inactivity:
>   always or just when the focussed window is not over the launcher (0 =
>   Never, 1 = Autohide, 2 = Dodge Windows, 3 = Dodge Active Window)

I believe the option you are looking for is 0

Comment: It's set to 0, but the launcher doesn't honor it.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> then type `compiz --replace`

Restart and try to change the **Hide Launcher** property on **CCSM** again.

*Try to set it from Never to Autohide, and then Never again.*

Comment: Nope, not working here...

Answer (score 0):

apparently 11.10 is no longer listening to what gconf has to say.

I had to install dconf and use it instead

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that the setting is under 

com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher

it took me some resizing of the window on my side to get it to show the setting properly, but I got it now.

just check the box, then hit your super key. launcher comes up, but doesn't hide :D:D:D:D

Comment: Doing this just makes the launcher disappear for me.  Again the OP is asking for the non-2d solution to this problem.