# Left edge mouse hoover doesn't bring up Unity menu when fullscreened

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher, multiple-monitors

When I have an app full-screened in 11.10, hoovering my mouse on the left edge doesn't bring up Unity menu. I have three 11.10 computers and this is only happening on the dual-screen twin-viewed Nvidia box. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this too from an upgrade but it wasn't related to nvidia. The resolution was to start 'ccsm' (Compizconfig settings manager), go to desktop, Unity plugin, and select "Dodge active window" next to "Hide Launcher".

Comment: That worked but I had to restart X after changing the setting - Thanks.

Comment: It actually looks like I just needed to change the "Hide Launcher" setting. I was able to change it back to "Dodge Windows" once it was working.

Answer (score 1):

I found rebooting fixes the issue. I am not using multiple monitors, I have it running on a laptop.

When this happens the Launcher IS actually appearing, but doing so behind the other windows. I can actually see it behind my partially transparent terminal window. I can see is slide out and go back away.

The other weird thing is this: It thinks it is in front. I can hover over an apps icon, and see the name appear (back there behind the terminal) and I can even click on one and launch the app.

Comment: Oh, and when this happens, the alt-tab switcher wont come to the front either.