# How to keep launcher on top?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I always show the launcher (i.e. disable the auto-hide functionality)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64858/how-do-i-always-show-the-launcher-i-e-disable-the-auto-hide-functionality)

It takes too long to show the launcher, and I work faster when it is always visible.
Therefore I would like to keep it on top. Is this possible?

Comment: ok! Thx. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, this is what you want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior