# Where can I get a list of SCHEMA / PATH / KEY to use with gsettings?

Tags: compiz, dconf, gsettings, gconf

After doing some research, I found that I can quickly set configuration options using the `gsettings` command in the terminal, instead of installing `dconf-editor` or `gconf-editor` or CCSM.

But we need the SCHEMA/PATH and KEY to set the value.
Syntax is:

```
gsettings set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE
```

For example to never auto-hide the launcher:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode 0
```

And, for windows not to overlap the launcher:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher use-strut true
```

So, where can I get a list of all the SCHEMA / PATH / KEY that can be set with gsettings?

No, please don't suggest the `gsettings list-keys` command, because I don't know the possibly hundreds of schema available.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`gsettings list-schemas` gets you all the schema. You can also use `gsettings list-recursively` for what you want but this program will list all the values for all the keys for all schemas:
(Lest's call the script `gsettings-iterate-all`)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Gnome 3 can be customised from the command line via the gsettings command
# This script should help you to find what you're looking for by
# listing the ranges for all keys for each schema

for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas | sort)
do
    for key in $(gsettings list-keys $schema | sort)
    do
        value="$(gsettings range $schema $key | tr "\n" " ")"
        echo "$schema :: $key :: $value"
    done
done
```

Expanding on your example `gsettings-iterate-all | grep com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher`  yields

```
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: edge-decayrate :: type i 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: edge-overcome-pressure :: type i 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: edge-responsiveness :: type d 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: edge-reveal-pressure :: type i 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: edge-stop-velocity :: type i 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: hide-mode :: type i 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: only-one-launcher :: type b 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: reveal-mode :: type i 
com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher :: super-key-enable :: type b
```

You can reroute the output to a file for easy reading.

And for creative folks out there. [Here is a list of possible options to gsettings that might help create other scripts](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gsettings-tool.html).

Comment: Rinzwind, Thank you for the additional useful information. I realized after I posted the question that a full list was available using the command  gsettings list-recursively, but like you say, you have given great additional info for creative folks :)

Comment: If you want the keys' default value, this may be of interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/196896/how-to-read-default-key-value-with-dconf-or-gsettings

Comment: Very useful ! +1

Comment: @Rinzwind As a practical note that may be useful: Do not call call a test script `test` (I edited it out).  Starting `test` will work just fine - and perfectly do it's job.   But it may be `/usr/bin/test`; To make it really fast, it's also a shell builtin. -  It's job with no arguments is to return exit code `0` and keep quiet. (see `man test`)

Comment: An enhancement suggestion: change to `for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas | grep "^$1" | sort)`, to allow things like `gsettings-iterate-all com.canonical`

Comment: For anyone trying to find and disable/modify a certain keybinding, check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372065/713476) which uses a slightly modified version of the same script. The thing is, if you are looking for a certain **value** from GSettings, the script above does not print out the **values**, so you must use `list-recursively` for that.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late, but I just started wrestling with this privacy concern...

It looks like `com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search 'none'` is the toggle you seek.

Comment: The question asks about where we can get the list of complete Schema. You are providing the one which relates to privacy. This doesn't really answer the question that is asked.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been using the code from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155321/279745) for years, now I’ve found some time to improve it by creating a JSON object per key (the actual output is an array of objects). It is opinionated and it could be improved (I am open to suggestions), however, it works for the schemas, keys and values I have on my system. I have also added the default value of each key (based on [this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196916/279745)). It also supports running `gsettings` in containers of Flatpak apps (although be warned that it is much slower) and filtering schemas using a search string that is understood by GNU `grep` (without any `grep` options).

### Example objects

```json
[
  {
    "currentValue": false,
    "dataType": "b",
    "defaultValue": false,
    "key": "symbolic-status-icons",
    "schema": "org.blueman.general",
    "type": "type"
  },
    {
    "currentValue": 60,
    "dataType": "i",
    "defaultValue": 60,
    "key": "time",
    "schema": "org.blueman.plugins.discvmanager",
    "type": "type"
  },
    {
    "currentValue": "[{\"adapter\": \"64:79:F0:BE:E9:51\", \"address\": \"C0:DC:DA:14:F7:FB\", \"alias\": \"note10\", \"icon\": \"phone\", \"name\": \"Audio a
nd input profiles\", \"uuid\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\", \"time\": \"1702752276.9439752\"}]",
    "dataType": "aa{ss}",
    "defaultValue": "@aa{ss} []",
    "key": "recent-connections",
    "schema": "org.blueman.plugins.recentconns",
    "type": "type"
  },
  {
    "currentValue": 2.3999999999999999,
    "dataType": "d",
    "defaultValue": 2.3999999999999999,
    "key": "display-gamma",
    "schema": "org.freedesktop.ColorHelper",
    "type": "type"
  },
  {
    "currentValue": -1,
    "dataType": "i",
    "defaultValue": -1,
    "key": "crawling-interval",
    "max": 365,
    "min": -2,
    "schema": "org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files",
    "type": "range"
  },
  {
    "currentValue": "last",
    "defaultValue": "last",
    "enumList": [
      "last",
      "next"
    ],
    "key": "new-tab-position",
    "schema": "org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings",
    "type": "enum"
  },
  {
    "currentValue": 0.66000000000000003,
    "dataType": "d",
    "defaultValue": 0.66000000000000003,
    "key": "cross-hairs-opacity",
    "max": 1.0,
    "min": 0.0,
    "schema": "org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier",
    "type": "range"
  },
  {
    "currentValue": 500,
    "dataType": "u",
    "defaultValue": 500,
    "key": "delay",
    "schema": "org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard",
    "type": "type"
  }
]
```

### Function definition

```bash
# Dependendies:
# - Bash;
# - GNU `grep`;
# - GNU `sed`;
# - `gsettings`;
# - `jq`;
# - (optional) `flatpak`.

gsls() {
  # Variables
  # Note: Use `search_string` to limit the schemas. It could be any regex string that GNU grep understands without any option provided.
  # Note: Use empty string to search for any schema in a Flatpak app, however, note that running `gsettings` in a Flatpak app (container) takes much longer than doing it directly on the host.
  # Note: `app` must be a valid Flatpak app ID.
  local search_string="$1"
  local app="$2"
  local data=''
  local cmd key schema

  if [ -z "$app" ]; then
    cmd='gsettings'
  else
    if ! command -v flatpak &> /dev/null; then
      # shellcheck disable=SC2016  # Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that
      echo 'ERROR: `flatpak` cannot be found in `PATH`.'
      return
    fi

    cmd="flatpak run --command=gsettings $app"
  fi


  # Cycle through matching schemas
  for schema in $($cmd list-schemas | grep "$([ -n "$search_string" ] && echo "$search_string" || echo '.*')"); do
    # Cycle through all keys of matching schemas
    for key in $($cmd list-keys "$schema"); do
      local current_value default_value type type_string
      type_string="$($cmd range "$schema" $key | tr "\n" " ")"
      type="$(grep -Po '^[^ ]+' <<< "$type_string")"
      current_value="$($cmd get "$schema" "$key" | sed "s/'/\"/g")"
      default_value="$(XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/nonexistent $cmd get "$schema" "$key" | sed "s/'/\"/g")"

      # Add those object properties to `data` which are the same for any `type`
      data+="{\"schema\": \"$schema\", \"key\": \"$key\", \"type\": \"$type\", "

      case "$type" in
        'enum')
          data+="\"enumList\": [$(sed "s/^enum \(.*\) $/\1/;s/ /, /g;s/'/\"/g" <<< "$type_string")], \"currentValue\": $current_value, \"defaultValue\": $default_value}"
        ;;
        'range')
          data+="\"dataType\": \"$(grep -Po "^$type \K[^ ]+" <<< "$type_string")\", \"min\": $(grep -Po "^$type [^ ]+ \K[^ ]+" <<< "$type_string"), \"max\": $(grep -Po "^$type [^ ]+ [^ ]+ \K[^ ]+" <<< "$type_string"), \"currentValue\": $current_value, \"defaultValue\": $default_value}"
        ;;
        'type')
          local data_type
          data_type="$(grep -Po "^$type \K[^ ]+" <<< "$type_string")"

          if grep -q '^@' <<< "$current_value"; then
            # shellcheck disable=SC2001  # See if you can use ${variable//search/replace} instead
            current_value="$(sed 's/^@[^ ]\+ //' <<< "$current_value")"

            # shellcheck disable=SC2001  # See if you can use ${variable//search/replace} instead
            default_value="$(sed 's/^@[^ ]\+ //' <<< "$default_value")"
          fi

          # Add double quotes when the value is not a boolean or a number or an array of a basic type or an optional boolean
          if ! grep -q '^[bdhinqstux]$\|^a[a-z]*$\|^mb$' <<< "$data_type"; then
            current_value="\"$current_value\""
            default_value="\"$default_value\""
          # Remove everything up to rightmost space of number types
          # Note: This is required because values of some types are prepended by their types (e.g. `uint32 3`).
          elif grep -q '^[nqtux]$' <<< "$data_type"; then
            current_value="${current_value//* /}"
            default_value="${default_value//* /}"
          # Replace `nothing` of `mb` (optional boolean) type with `null`
          elif grep -q '^mb$' <<< "$data_type" && grep -q '^nothing$' <<< "$current_value"; then
            current_value='null'
          fi

          # Replace `nothing` of `mb` (optional boolean) type with `null`
          if grep -q '^mb$' <<< "$data_type" && grep -q '^nothing$' <<< "$default_value"; then
            default_value='null'
          fi

          data+="\"dataType\": \"$data_type\", \"currentValue\": $([ "$data_type" = 'as' ] && echo "$current_value" || sed -z "s/\"/\\\\\"/g;s/\(^\\\\\"\|\\\\\"\n*$\)/\"/g" <<< "$current_value"), \"defaultValue\": $([ "$data_type" = 'as' ] && echo "$default_value" || sed -z "s/\"/\\\\\"/g;s/\(^\\\\\"\|\\\\\"\n*$\)/\"/g" <<< "$default_value")}"
        ;;
      esac
    done
  done

  # Output a JSON string (array of objects)
  # Note: The `-S` option sorts the keys alphabetically.
  # Note: The `-s` option is required, as `jq` is used to merge individual JSON strings (documents) into an array.
  # Note: `sort_by(.key) | sort_by(.schema)` sorts the objects in the array first by `schema`, then by `key`.
  jq -Ss 'sort_by(.key) | sort_by(.schema)' <<< "$data"
}
```

### Usage examples

```bash
# Get all keys of all schemas
# Note: It takes about 16-18 seconds to complete on my computer (the length of the returned array is 679).
gsls | less

# Get all keys from schemas matching `terminal`
gsls terminal | less

# Get all keys from schemas matching `Prompt` in the Flatpak app `org.gnome.Prompt.Devel` (GNOME Prompt)
# Note: It takes about 11-12 seconds to complete on my computer (the length of the returned array is 49).
gsls Prompt org.gnome.Prompt.Devel | less
```

### List of data types

FYI, here is a list (cheatsheet) of all types that could be used in `gsettings`. For more information, see the [docs](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.VariantType.html#description).

```bash
(...) = tuple
* = any
? = basic
a = array
b = boolean
d = double
g = signature
h = int32_file_desc
i = int32
m = maybe/nullable/optional
n = int16
o = object_path
q = uint16
r = indefinite_tuple
s = string
t = uint64
u = uint32
v = variant
x = int64
y = byte
{...} = dictionary_entry/object
```

### Possible future improvements

Some stuff to improve:

- use `getopt`;
- convert `dataType` to a more meaningful value (e.g. `b` → `boolean`; see the data type list above);
- make the sorting optional;
- optimise the function so that it runs faster (possibly by utilising `gsettings list-recursively`).