# How to read default key value with dconf or gsettings?

Tags: default, restore, gconf, gsettings

I would like to know the default value of a dconf/gsettings key.

My question is a followup of the question below:
[Where can I get a list of SCHEMA / PATH / KEY to use with gsettings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155305/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-schema-path-key-to-use-with-gsettings)

What I'm trying to do, so create a script that reads all my personal preferences so I can back them up and restore them.  I plan to iterate though all keys, like the script above, see what keys have been changed from their default value, and make a note of these, that can be restored later.

I see that the dconf-editor display the keys' default value, but I'd very much like to script this.  Also, I don't see how parsing the schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/ can be automated.  Maybe someone can help?

gsettings get-default|list-defaults would be nice =)

(Geesh, it was much easier in the old days where you just kept your ~/.somethingrc in subversion ... =\

---

**Based on the answer given below,** I've updated the script to print schema, key, key's data type, **default value**, and actual value:

```
#!/bin/bash

for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas | sort); do
    for key in $(gsettings list-keys $schema | sort); do
        type="$(gsettings range $schema $key | tr "\n" " ")"
        default="$(XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/tmp/ gsettings get $schema $key | tr "\n" " ")"
        value="$(gsettings get $schema $key | tr "\n" " ")"
        echo "$schema :: $key :: $type :: $default :: $value"
    done
done
```

This workaround basically covers what I need.  I'll continue working on the backup scrip from here.

Comment: If anyone else also got here looking for how to reset a key to its default value, then `gsettings reset KEY` is the way to go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There does not seem to be a nice way to get at the default values directly, but since the client checks XDG_CONFIG_HOME in the environment a decent workaround to get values from a fresh config might be:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/nonexistent gsettings get SCHEMA KEY
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can use the same approach with `dconf` as well e.g. `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/nonexistent dconf read /path/to/key`

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in backing up and restore your settings (in this case you should change the title of your question).

### Backup

You can backup your settings with

```
gsettings list-recursively > backup
```

This writes all keys to the file *backup* in you Home-Folder.

### Restore

As far as I know there isn't any direct option to import the file back to dconf.
Maybe you could write a routine that reads the backup file line by line and executes `gsettings set <input line from backup>` to restore your settings.