# How do I dump all the manually altered dconf / gsettings keys?

Tags: dconf, gsettings

dconf editor indicates the keys whose values have been altered by the user by changing the key's font to bold as shown in the snapshot.

[image: snap1]

So I wonder if there is a way to dump all the keys (including their schema) which have been modified manually by user or changed to something other than the default? That would prove very helpful to solve many desktop environment issues, or at least for me :)

Comment: This question shows how to get default values from gsettings, you can probably tweak the script in the question to do what you need: http://askubuntu.com/questions/196896/how-to-read-default-key-value-with-dconf-or-gsettings

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`dconf` provides such an option (Ref: `man dconf`)

- To dump only user-altered keys:

  ```
    dconf dump / > dump.dconf
  ```
- To restore:

  ```
    dconf load / < dump.dconf
  ```

Comment: You can add `dconf dump / | gzip -9 > ~/Dropbox/Backup/dconf-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%T).bak.gz` to your `/etc/cron.monthly/`.

Comment: How to dump all keys incl. default? To my surprise `dconf list /x/dm/slick-greeter` just shows the 1 property I just changed, not the 2 dozen (in light gray) `dconf-editor` shows...  (apparently those “defaults” come from gsettings? `gsettings list-recursively | grep "x.dm.slick"` does the job.

Comment: @FrankNocke yes, gsettings shows the final value of the keys as user apps see it through gsettings API. `gsettings list-recursively` is the  only way i know but it does not show reallocated schemas. Beaware of gsettings values priority list: locks, user db, system db (system db is compiled from: overrides, schemas defaults)