# Is it now possible to use a blacklisted Nvidia 7200 card in Unity? 

Tags: unity, 11.10, nvidia

I heard that the Nvidia 7200 GS card [has been blacklisted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity) since Natty. Also, I read that you can add `unity_force_start=1` to `/etc/environment` to use Unity 3D. That doesn't seem to work for me though.

I can play 3D required games such as Neverball and Nexuiz, but I also want to be able to use Unity 3D, because the 2D version is pretty unusable, at least for me.

Is there any workaround to get Unity working for me? INB4 get a new graphic card.

PS: Current driver I am using: 280.13

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 and my 7200 SE isn't the most performant but seems to chugging along acceptably.  When I'm running 3840x1200 desktop resolution, it has some noticable lag even in the 2D version of unity offered, but overall it worked well enough.  I did have `UNITY_FORCE_START=1` in my `/etc/environment` file already, and it persisted through the upgrade, maybe yours wasn't working due to case sensitivity?