# nVidia GeForce Go 7600? can it ever run unity?

Tags: unity

My laptop, a Toshiba Qosmio G30, has a nVidia  GeForce Go 7600 graphics card and it's suppose to support 3D . I am running unity 2d now . The graphic driver is `--VESA: G73 Board - toshg73m--` by **Ubuntu**. When I run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` I got this list:

```
Not software rendered: no 
Not blacklisted: yes 
GLX fbconfig: yes 
GLX texture from pixmap: yes 
GL npot or rect textures: 
yes GL vertex program: yes 
GL fragment program: yes 
GL vertex buffer object: yes 
GL framebuffer object: yes 
GL version is 1.4+: yes
Unity 3D supported: no
```

The card is not blacklisted but a similar one with GT is!

Do you think that there is a chance the laptop can run the unity 3d? Maybe I could change the resolution of the screen to a higher one too! I tried all the nvidia drivers provided but none works (except 96 in ubuntu 12.04 ). I get a black screen or terminal screen.

Best Wishes to All

Comment: if any of these answers "answered" your question please accept one of them :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out

copy this in the terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

and then add this

```
UNITY_FORCE_START=1
```

in the teksteditor to `/etc/environment`

then save the file and reboot

**Source**:

- [Enable unity 3D with nvidia 7xxx vga - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/enable-unity-3d-under-nvidia-7xxx-vga)
- [Geforce Go 7300/7400 Blacklisted, Can I Still Run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity)

Comment: i got a unity 3D however the screen is not stable blinking and programs appearing and disappearing! also system error messages  where i can not cancel them . so i followed the link 
under and could not install current 173 ...it gives an error message:
that there is a conflict with some software installed !

Comment: i found the environmet file is starage . it looks like this
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

is that look right to you?

Comment: Add the in the next line, the **UNITY_FORCE_START=1** command