# Ubuntu 12.04 NVIDIA GeForce Go 7600 black screen during boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia, grub2

I'm using Ubuntu as the only operating system since two years. In the first Ubuntu versions I had seen my BIOS screen and the boot screens. Actually im using Ubuntu 12.04 and my screen stays black until Ubuntu is started (both screens are missing). I guess this situation appeared the first time in Ubuntu 11 (not sure).

I searched via google and tried the popular activities but was not able to fix my issue. I opened the laptop and checked all connections. I'm using boot option nomodeset. I had a look through many many web pages. I don't know how to continue and hope somebody could be helpful.

My hardware:
Acer Aspire 9300
AMD Turion 64 x2
NVIDIA GeForce Go 7600 (using proposed driver)

```
lspci | grep NVIDIA
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:00.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 0 (rev a2)
00:00.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 1 (rev a2)
00:00.3 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 5 (rev a2)
00:00.4 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 4 (rev a2)
00:00.5 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:00.6 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 3 (rev a2)
00:00.7 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 2 (rev a2)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:09.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:0a.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 LPC Bridge (rev a3)
00:0a.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 SMBus (rev a3)
00:0a.3 Co-processor: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PMU (rev a3)
00:0b.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:0b.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:0d.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 IDE (rev f1)
00:0e.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller (rev f1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PCI Bridge (rev a2)
00:10.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:14.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Ethernet Controller (rev a3)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G73 [GeForce Go 7600] (rev a1)
```

So my question is what to do to fix the black screen during boot?

Comment: Please see this questions to further help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/145675/nvidia-geforce-go-7600-can-it-ever-run-unity http://askubuntu.com/questions/145675/nvidia-geforce-go-7600-can-it-ever-run-unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and give your password. Find the line that says:

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

(that is, remove the pound sign).

Then, run close Text Editor and run `sudo update-grub`. It may take a while ,but when it finishes, you will get the familiar `user@computer ~$` prompt, which means the command is done. Reboot, and it should help.

Comment: Thank you very much! Kexec is installed now. Did reboot and a shutdown with normal boot afterwards but the situation is still the same.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidt that's weird--I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: I aggree. Tried not to understand the kernel issues until now. I installed kdump also but didn't help. I'm looking forward to you answer!

Comment: @FlorianSchmidt Kdump is not being used to look for kernel issues--It is a workaround that does something to kernel graaphics sode that could help--possibly a bug.

Comment: Hi ObsessiveFOSS, did you find a further solution?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidt Sorry, I kept forgetting to attend to this question. I will edit very soon.

Comment: I tried this option but now my laptop is unable to boot now. BIOS gives one long and two short beep tones. Google says this is a graphic card fault. I did undo this option and my "nomodeset" option but didn't help.

The hard disk of my second laptop get's the same fault. So it seems as if the grub menu isn't the problem and the graphic card causes this problem at the moment. I'm going to open the many screws to check the cable connection soon and inform afterwards.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidt Now, this looks like a coincidence.

Comment: @ObsessivFoss Thank you very much for you help! Because of my BIOS beap tones I repaired my mainbord with the oven method (just google). My BIOS and boot screen appeared again. So my issue has been a hardware defect and baking in the oven really works, unbelievable!

Comment: Yes, I did. This reactivates broken connections on the mainboard. I couldn't believe until I tried yesterday. And it worked! Graphic card is running again.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidt It's good that it's working now. Would you mind adding that as an answer and accepting it?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidt I meant adding your own answer and accepting *that*. My answer did not directly solve your problem so it should not be accepted.