# Ubuntu 14.04 server sleeps after login screen

Tags: 14.04, suspend

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 lts, the server starts to boot just fine and it gets to the login screen it takes 4 seconds and it goes to sleep mode I think as I can hear the PSU fan running but I cannot resume, ping or do anything but restart it manually(pressing the power button) if I go in recovery mode it doesnt have this issue, any hints will be appreciatted.

Cheers,

Comment: Can you go to recovery mode https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode and go to settings and then power management and turn sleep off, then restart

Comment: Do you use a Nvidia GPU ? I found this if you do http://askubuntu.com/questions/470915/clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-screen-goes-black-after-login-but-mouse-works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the kernel options "acpi=off apm=off" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub?

Then run sudo update-grub and reboot your computer.

or else follow this link

https://superuser.com/questions/155881/how-do-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-putting-my-monitor-to-sleep

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.