# How to fix error "Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display"?

Tags: graphics, intel, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-geforce

When I try to confirm than I can run Unity 3D on my Asus U31SD with intel's i5 Sandy Brigde and Nvidia 520 and Nvidia Optimus I receive this error:
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

Of course, I cannot run any of the effects of Ubuntu 11.10, not even the simple app switcher.

Can anybody help me? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs when you install the proprietary nvidia driver on NVidia Optimus laptop. The nvidia card cannot directly be used due to the Optimus design. To repair this, uninstall the `nvidia-current` package and re-login. After that, you'll solely be running off the Intel graphics card which renders the nvidia card unused though it'll still be using power. Bumblebee allows you to switch off the card, see [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

Comment: I removed and purged `nvidia-current` but there is still the error "extension GLX missing on display :0".

Comment: @broiyan If you have an Optimus laptop, please see the linked question.

Comment: Yes, I have an Optimus card. I tried removing nvidia-current via the command line and still Ubuntu Software Center thinks it's installed.  I tried various things at the link as well, including rebooting to uninstall the Nvidia 295.53 driver.  Still I can't get glxspheres to run.  My aim is to get 32 pixel icons in the Launcher and that's why I'm using Optimus.

Comment: If you are using Bumblebee, you can try to get help from the IRC channel #bumblebee on Freenode IRC. Ensure that /etc/X11/xorg.conf is removed, that you have not installed the nvidia driver directly from nvidia.com and then reinstall Bumblebee using: `sudo apt-get purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-current && sudo apt-get install bumblebee`. Reboot (or restart the DE) and try again.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember well GLX have something to do with OpenGL windowsing in X systems. So make sure you install mesa package which is implementation of OGL in Linux

Comment: Installed "mesa-vulkan-drivers" and the error was fixed!

Comment: actually, that helped

Answer (score 2):

Is that a system with 2 graphics cards? If so, the following makes google earth work for me:
https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable

As that page mentiones, you could always try experimental drivers, although that alone didn't solve my problems.
Open a console and type:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

or, if you're feeling lucky, the latest-but-less-stable:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

then update the drivers

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install nvidia-current ppa-purge
```

and update /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    nvidia-xconfig

Note that the last step breaks my system. I have restore the old xorg.conf to make it work again:

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

The 'driver' line in the 'device' section is what's giving me problems.
For more details, see:
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

and launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Comment: see also
http://askubuntu.com/questions/37590/nvidia-drivers-not-working-after-upgrade-why-can-i-only-see-terminal

Answer (score 2):

I have a Dell Latitude E6240 with nVidia card. Just this afternoon I noticed an optimus option in the bios which indicated it was only for Windows 7 32-64 bit, turned it of and voila. I have no more errors, Cheese Webcam Booth worked and certain features (probably Unity) started to work. (transparent windows, Expo/DesktopWall worked properly)

Answer (score 0):

For the proper way to setup bumblebee, check the "power consumption" section on the Ubuntu wiki here (I just edited it in):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Asus_U31SD

This question is a little old, but I put it here for people to find.

Answer (score 0):

I have a NVIDIA GTX 550 ti in my computer and install the driver from nvidia.com. I encounter this issue when I finish upgrade operation

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

So I tried to reinstall the driver and it works.

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.67.run
```