# How to fix: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display. Ubuntu running on Oracle VM Virtual Box

Tags: 12.04, c++, opengl

I have been assigned a homework on my C++ class using OpenGL and GLUT. When I try to run the project, it runs very slowly and it freezes after a little bit. Before the program runs I get the following error:

```
extension "NV-GLX" missing on display
```

If have tried:

- Installing the driver from NVIDIA website.
- Installing the driver by following the instructions in this thread: [extension "GLX" missing on display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67567/extension-glx-missing-on-display)
- Installing/Uninstalling the drivers several times.

All of this without any success. I am not a Linux expert, and this is my first time dealing with Linux seriously, so if you could please set me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are running Ubuntu under virtual box, you don't need the Ubuntu drivers - you just need the virtualbox virtual display driver. You can get it by installing the VirtualBox "guest additions"

Comment: After very long this is what I did and it worked just fine. Thanks for your help mate.