# ERROR:Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0". while opening sumo-gui

Tags: 12.04, drivers, gui

I have installed SUMO simulator for my research work, but I am unable to open its GUI. When I entered the command `sumo-gui` I get this error:

```
ERROR:Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0". 
Error: This system has no OpenGL support. Exiting. Quitting (on error)
```

Version of sumo 0.29.0 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please paste the error in proper format. This is very hard to read. I don't think all the error message is in one line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extension "GLX" missing on display](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67567/extension-glx-missing-on-display)