# Nvidia GTS450, turn on nvidia drivers = blank screen after boot

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia

I know this is possibly a duplicate of [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver). But now 11.10 has been released.  Is this issue near to being resolved?

I've even uninstalled the nouveau drivers and have installed the unified drivers from nvidia, I get the same.  Upon reboot the system boots up, I see the root prompt flash up and then it tries to load up unity but then the screen goes blank and the monitor turns off.

Now on the 7th installation of 11.10 and this time I think I will leave as is.  As a side issue, XFCE has a 3d drivers option which works for me, as I was just running 11.04 today.  Why this option is unavailable for Ubuntu, I am unsure...

Any help appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found in the monitor section that my monitors where set to mirror.  I changed that and now they are both working out of the box.  So really I have no need for the nvidia drivers as this is really just a development box.

Answer (score 0):

There are still nVidia issues/problems.  I can only speak from experience that I've had trying to install 11.10 with a EVGA GeForce nVidia graphics card.

Did you make sure to pull the driver from the repository?

Did you try to blacklist the other drivers?

Also, I found this to be a helpful thread.

[NVIDIA drivers not working after upgrade. Why can I only see terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37590/nvidia-drivers-not-working-after-upgrade-why-can-i-only-see-terminal)