# Restart when I go to /home or run certain programs

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NVIDIA drivers not working after upgrade. Why can I only see terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37590/nvidia-drivers-not-working-after-upgrade-why-can-i-only-see-terminal)

After the last update, Ubuntu 11.10 restarts when I try `/home`, Texmaker, Texstudio, Kile or VirtualBox, but LibreOffice, Firefox, etc., work fine...

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I read [NVIDIA drivers not working after upgrade. Why can I only see terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37590/nvidia-drivers-not-working-after-upgrade-why-can-i-only-see-terminal). So I've  removed all files xorg.config*.* from  directory  /etc/X11/  and restart... and  problems has gone!