# Graphic Interface doesn't start

Tags: 12.04, unity, xorg, gui

I came back to work after a week away and this is what greets me:

[image]

If I press enter it displays the tty1 login prompt.

I have booted using a 12.04.2 Live USB and it seems to work fine, I`m using it to write this.

I have no idea where to start or what to look for. There are no USB devices attached, besides mouse and keyboard. The same message shows up if I disconnect both and reboot.

Either selecting a "previous linux version" on grub, or `apt-get dist upgrade` doesn't solve my issue.

Here's the content of `Xorg.*.log` files in `/var/log`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5613488

Comment: It's likely that that's just a boot message and has nothing to do with the actual problem. Log in and look in `/var/log/Xorg.0.logvar/log/Xorg.0.log` for actual errors. If you have network, you can use something like `pastebinit` to post that online (it should be relatively safe but will probably contain your hostname)

Comment: @oli Isn't it `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`? In this case, I'm pasting its contents now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved removing removing video drivers from Nvidia:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-304 nvidia-experimental-310
sudo aptitude purge ~c
```

Comment: related, see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37590/nvidia-drivers-not-working-after-upgrade-why-can-i-only-see-terminal