# Unity not starting with nvidia driver install

Tags: unity, nvidia

I just installed the two nvidia drivers from the restricted drivers section when I was prompted thinking that it will improve my performance. But after I restarted the computer a prompt came up saying that I did not have the appropriated hardware to run the unity server (which is odd as it was running smoothly before). What can I do about this?

Comment: Do you get a similar screen as shown in this question? [Nvidia driver activated but currently not in use](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37084/nvidia-driver-activated-but-currently-not-in-use) if so it is a know bug, in addition I would only activate the recommended driver.

Comment: Try removing "Experimental 3D support for NVIDIA cards" as this is for the open source driver Nouveau. Don't forget to reboot.

Comment: Done, I removed those and its working again

Answer (score 2):

> Try removing "Experimental 3D support for NVIDIA cards" as this is for the open source driver Nouveau.
>
> Don't forget to reboot

- [htorque](https://askubuntu.com/users/3037/htorque) - [May 3 '11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39608/unity-not-starting-with-nvidia-driver-install/105445#comment43442_39608)

[comment from OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39608/unity-not-starting-with-nvidia-driver-install/105445#comment43492_39608):

> Done, I removed those and its working again