# How do I use an activated(but not in use) driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nvidia driver activated but currently not in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37084/nvidia-driver-activated-but-currently-not-in-use)

Under **System > Administration > Additional Drivers** It shows that I have a driver active but not in use. How can I activate it?

this window-[image]

Comment: Many people are having issues - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742640 there's all type of bug reports throughout that post.