# 11.10 7600gt display error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display

So i used to use Ubuntu back when it was 8 and it never gave me any problems but recently i did a fresh install of 11.10. But now when i install the N-Vidia restricted drivers i cant change my screen resolution from 640x480, the display menu says "can not detect display".

There is no way to navigate the screen really because the windows don't work and I'm not very command prompt keen please help i love Ubuntu!

Comment: Looks your your card is no longer supported in the new drivers, do not install them and use the default drivers Ubuntu comes with.

Comment: The Display menu doesn't work with proprietary Nvidia drivers. Use nvidia settings instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you blacklist nouveau-driver, when using nvidia-driver?

Maybe this thread can help you (2nd answer): [blacklist nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59037/how-to-get-nvidia-driver-working-properly-running-experimental-3d-support)

Comment: thank you that thread help blacklisting worked, drivers work Unity is pretty cool.