# Why I can't use my Nvidia video driver with Gnome-Shell?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, gnome

I've a notebook Asus Aspire 5742G with a video card Nvidia GeForce GT 540M.
If I install raccomended driver from jockey, Gnome shell after login goes into fallback mode.
Can I solve this?

Comment: I'd like to note that this also happens with proprietary drivers for the ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6800 series. Gnome-shell works fine when I use the open source drivers, though.

Answer (score 1):

I use the same video card and had to blacklist the nouveau driver when installing the nvidia_current driver via jockey.

See here for advice: [blacklist nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59037/how-to-get-nvidia-driver-working-properly-running-experimental-3d-support)

Hint: After installing nvidia_current, jockey still says it is not in use. This is a jockey bug. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I never use the nvidia_current drivers as they are outdated, try getting the latest driver from Nvidia website and installing it manually. Here in [my AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers) I have got a pretty good answer on how to do this.