# Why is my NVIDIA Additional Driver Installed but not in use

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nvidia driver activated but currently not in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37084/nvidia-driver-activated-but-currently-not-in-use)

I am on Ubuntu 11.04, NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GT, Ubuntu Classic. Why is my driver installed but now in use?

[image]