# HD5450 "This driver is actived but currently not in use"

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I don't understand why I can't find the answer to the simple question of how to get a driver status changed from "Activated but currently not in use" to in use. Install directions are not what I am looking for here, the drivers are already installed, I just need to get them to be used!

I have tried installing the proprietary drivers only to have segmentation faults when I ran startx. As well as "low graphics mode" warnings via lightdm.

I just want the HDMI port to work on my ubuntu server, so I can watch the traffic logs on my big screen. Please help with simple directions on how to SWITCH from the currently used drivers to the "currently not use" drivers.

There must be some config file to edit. I don't want uninstall and reinstall directions.

Answer (score 0):

drivers needs to be loaded in kernel, so u need to restart that server, i guess u did?

this question was discussed here already, maybe that helps:

[Driver not in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37084/nvidia-driver-activated-but-currently-not-in-use)