# How do I force Unity to not use compositing?

Tags: 11.04, unity-2d, compositing

Unity 3D is incredibly unstable for me. Still, I love the interface and would like to continue using it. Is there any way to force Unity 2D?

Btw: I've already filed a bug report against `xserver-xorg-video-ati`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install [unity-2d](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity-2d) [image: Install unity-2d] and reboot. At GDM login screen, in the drop-down box at the bottom of the screen select 'Ubuntu Unity 2D session'. In consequent bootups, the Unity 2D session will become the default.

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

If you want to enable/disable composting in Unity 2D, you can install the Unity 2D tweaking tool by following [this guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/ubuntu-unity-2d-tweaking-tool-lets-you-adjust-the-launcher-dash-enable-compositing/).