# Resizing a window freezes the entire system

Tags: 11.04, freeze, resize

I have just installed Natty on an Intel Celeron single core CPU with 1 GB RAM without a 3D graphic card and Natty is running on Classic Desktop instead of Unity.

I have to force turn off and restart the computer system to recover.

Maximizing, minimizing and restoring do not freeze the system. Only when I tried to click and drag the border to resize my computer system freeze with the window having a orangy tint.

Otherwise Natty run along nicely for now.

Comment: After reading about compiz freezed, and reading about using classic desktop without effect, I have decided to try this out. Log Off and choose classic desktop (without effect) and log in again. My problem disappear. I guess compiz is the culprit here.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I see you commented on your own question.  Just wanted to give you some options:

You can install 2d-unity as a work-around:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Then you choose it from the login window as "2d Unity", I think.  This will look nearly the same as the default ubuntu desktop, but without 3d acceleration.

Also, you may want to file a defect in launchpad if you can reliably reproduce the crash.  If you really feel like narrowing it down, you could open up "CompizConfig Settings Manager", and try turning of some features like "animations" or "fading windows" and see if one of those features is causing the crash.

Comment: I think the fault is due to my old Geforce 2 AGP card. It may have been detected as 3D as default but not capable of all the 3D effects.

Thank for the tip for the unity-2d-default-settings. Ubuntu Software Center should display this readily when I searched for "unity" but it did not. May be because it did not behave exactly like the unity 3D.

Thanks.