# Installed Unity 2D on 11.04, not showing in the login screen?

Tags: unity-2d

Downloaded & installed 11.04 and because I don't have 3D graphics, I thought I would try Unity 2D. Installed it from the Software Centre, logged out, when logging back in I don't have the option to use Unity 2D as it's not listed at the login session?

Comment: Thought I would add machine spec:  EMachine 3220, 2.80GHZ Intel Celeron Processor, 80GB hard drive, Intel Extreme Graphics 3D, 512 DDR

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Unity 2D:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Comment: Matt- It worked! Amazing. This command worked, but installing using the Software Centre didn't. Many thanks. I now have unity-2d

Comment: We need to post a bug report on this matter.