# As I can't use Unity (2D or 3D), is there any reason to use 11.04 over 10.04?

Tags: 11.04

As I can't use Unity (2D or 3D), is there any reason to use 11.04 over 10.04?

See my previous question: [Installed Unity 2D on 11.04, not showing in the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38321/installed-unity-2d-on-11-04-not-showing-in-the-login-screen)

Only difference I can see is Libre Office, Banshee Music Player. Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

There are many new packages, so, in normal case I would say it's worth the change, but!

Since I installed 11.04, I have tons of problems, preventing me from work, so I am moving back to 10.10 in some days. Sure, it has some nice new features (my WiFi connects much faster, general little improvements, and so on), but Natty seems unfinished for me. (Don't forget, the Ubuntu Classic desktop, which is the old Gnome one, is buggy in 11.04.)

Comment: Yeah, I am using the Ubuntu Classic desktop in 11.04. All seems pointless. Real shame. Back to 10.10 for me I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not necessarily advocating the user of a pre-relase version (although I'm running it), if the features of Unity appeal to you, don't forget 11.10 includes Unity2D which seems pretty awesome at least in my tests in VirtualBox. I would hate to run a version as old as 10.04 (or even 10.10) for daily use on a desktop, but that's just me.

Are there any specific examples of issues you are having with Classic GNOME in 11.04 I could help you work through?

Answer (score 1):

In the final release, Ubuntu 11.10 will have many new updates and changes that will hopefully improve your day to day use and Unity 2D/3D will have gone through a lot of bugfixes so that it will work on your system...  It wont hurt to try...