# How can I diagnose and report screen flickers in Unity after upgrading?

Tags: 11.04, unity, upgrade

I just upgraded and was excited to try Unity. I logged in normally, but got the following symptoms:

- Although my background image showed normally, all my icons and any windows I opened flickered in and out every few seconds
- I opened a Terminal window with a keyboard shortcut, but couldn't type anything in it
- I didn't see any menus for shutting down or logging out, so I had to do so with the power button

After rebooting, I tried Recovery Mode, but that eventually went to a black screen and did nothing else.

I succeeded in booting by doing this:

- Boot to "normal" Ubuntu (not Recovery Mode)
- Choose my user name
- While the password box is on the screen, choose "Ubuntu Classic" from the menu at the bottom
- Log in

Everything looks fine now, but I'm using GNOME and not Unity. **How can I diagnose my issues with Unity and get it working?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your graphics hardware I suspect you cannot run Unity, when you log into GNOME open a terminal and type the following;

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

It will let you know if your hardware supports Unity, if you get a NO response at the end you can always install Unity2D:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

You can then log out and Select *Unity 2D* at the log in screen

Comment: When I ran that test, it showed all passing. Should I report a bug?

Comment: Unity 2D works for me, by the way. Thanks!