# How to upgrade Unity on 10.10 UNR without upgrading Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, unity, upgrade

I keep on getting errors when trying to Upgrade, but really, I like my current setup so I just want the new Unity interface. How to I upgrade it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Compiz is [not backported](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/unity-compiz-wont-be-backported-to-maverick/) to 10.10. But if you want to check out unity. You can use Unity-2d. Here are the installation instructions [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop). Basically you can use compiz with unity-2d, [I did it in 10.10](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/142689). As far as netbook edition go, I think it is merged into desktop iso and a package named `ubuntu-netbook` is provided. You may try upgrading from iso which will try to keep up your current settings as well. But upgrading basically keeps your settings.

But you may search for [ppas](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). Since ubuntu 11.04 is not using gnome3 you may get lucky.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of creating a backport for Maverick was rejected. See https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2010-November/032078.html